# Flutter/Dart. Getting data between two dates in mongodb without using ISODATE

Tags: database, mongodb, datetime, flutter, dart

I'm using mongo 3.6. I have a DB with a field named `date` of type `Date`, and I want to return all my documents (`$find`) between two specific dates.

The problem is that I have to compose these queries in Flutter/Dart, so I cannot use `ISODATE()` to parse my dates because (to my knowledge) there's no such function, although I do have tried `.toIso8601String` with no luck.

Everything I try leads to and empty response (no documents returned, but no error also).

Things that I've tried:

`{"date": {"$gte": "2018-08-23T09:34:32.000Z"}}`

`{"date": {"$gte": [{ "$dateFromString": { "dateString": "$date" }}, "2018-08-23T09:34:32.000Z"]}}`

`{"date": {"$gte": {"$date":"2018-08-23T09:34:32.000Z"}}}`

`{"date": {"$gte": {"$date":"2018-08-23 09:34:32.000"}}}`

And many more.

Please, does anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You might using [mongo_dart](https://pub.dev/packages/mongo_dart) package and see its repository (specially the method [testDateTime](https://github.com/mongo-dart/mongo_dart/blob/master/test/database_test.dart#L116)). Then you could do something as:

```dart
var collectionName = 'users';
var collection = db.collection(collectionName);

await collection.insertAll([
    { 'name': 'John', 'birthday_date': DateTime.utc(2018, 8, 23, 12, 00, 00) },
    { 'name': 'Alice', 'birthday_date': DateTime.utc(2018, 8, 23, 10, 43, 24) },
    { 'name': 'Jim', 'birthday_date': DateTime.utc(2018, 8, 23, 8, 30, 0) }
]);

var result = await collection
    .find(where.gte('birthday_date', DateTime.utc(2018, 8, 23, 9, 34, 32)))
    .toList();
```